# Calculating sequential numbers into sorted table not dependent on OBJECTID?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, field-calculator, python-parser

I am having a problem with adding sequential numbers to the new column based on other sorted value. I would like to use 'Sort by' column to be able to generate numbers in the 'Required number'column.

I have a script listed below (Field calculator) that allows me to generate numbers in 'Script used' column. Unfortunately, the numbers start from 0 instead of 11.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
lr=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]

tbl=arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(lr,("objectid","MapOrderNum"))#MapOrderNum is a field that you want to use to sorb by
bs=sorted(tbl,key=lambda x: x[1])
aDict={}
for i,row in enumerate(bs):
 aDict[row[0]]=i
def sortSeq(objectid):
 return aDict[objectid]

sortSeq ( !OBJECTID!)
```

[image]

Comment: Try to use `for i,row in enumerate(bs, 11)` instead of `for i,row in enumerate(bs)`

Comment: Or `return aDict[objectid]+11`. You can use da.SearchCursor instead of TableToNumPyArray, not sure what will be faster: `tbl = [i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lr, ["OID@","MapOrderNum"])]`. Will be a list of tuples which you can sort the same way.